# What happened to my account? Is it deleted?

Tags: support

I was trying to change my e-mail associated with my account. I clicked on mylogins and I clicked on "x" to the one I no longer wanted.

I then logged out and tried logging back in with my the e-mail I had added, but it said that account wasn't recognized(?). I then tried with my old e-mail address, and it was recognized, but my entire profile was gone (rep points, badges, name). This doesn't make sense to me. I didn't put in a request to have my account deleted.

My OpenId account is still active. So I don't know why I can't get back into my Stack Exchange account (hence why my username is user39902).

Is my account deleted?

Comment: Can you link to any answer/question posted from your old account?

Comment: Well the account definitely isn't deleted then, deleted accounts are anonymised with a greyed out avatar.

Comment: @MartinSmith how do i get back in? I tried using my usual login email and I end up in the user39902 account.

Comment: You'll probably need to wait for a moderator or SE staff to have a look at what's happened.

Comment: The email on that other account is completely different. It's a Gmail address, but that's about all I can tell you about it.

Comment: @MartinSmith Do I have to contact them? (Thanks btw for the replies, I'd vote up, but I can't)

Comment: @AnnaLear: Yeah, I tried logging in with that e-mail, but it links me to this account. I tried both the new one and the old one. The new one isn't recognized though...So I don't get what happened.

Comment: @user39902 Okay, drop us an email at team@stackoverflow.com and tell us what the email addresses involved are. We'll go from there.

Comment: @user39902 nevermind, I see the email you submitted from the support form. Stand by. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just for completeness' sake... your profiles have been merged. Enjoy!